# Random number using Date() in Expression Builder

Tags: ms-access, random, numbers, generated

I want to generate random number using `Date()` to format it like for example: `ddmmyyyyHhNnSs`

How do I achieve that? Is that even possible?
I was kinda hoping I can do it easy way by the expression builder but I seem to fail on each approach ;)

This number need to populate `txtID` field and it will be unique identifier for each database entry.

Comment: is there never more than 1 transaction in any given second?

Answer (score 0):

That's quite easy - with a twist.

Problem is that `Rnd` only returns a Single and the resolution of this only allows for 10000000 unique values. As you request a resolution to the second and with 86400 seconds per day, that only leaves a span of 115.74 days while the range of Date spans 3615899 days:

```
TotalDays = -CLng(#1/1/100#) + CLng(#12/31/9999#)
```

To overcome this, use `Rnd` twice which will result in 1E+15 possible values or 11574074074 days - way beyond what's needed:

```
RandomDouble = Rnd * Rnd
```

Now, to limit the possible values to fit into the range of data type Date, just follow the documentation:

```
RandomValue = (UpperValue - LowerValue) * Rnd + LowerValue
```

and apply the date values:

```
RandomDouble = (CLng(#12/31/9999#) - CLng(#1/1/100#)) * Rnd * Rnd + CLng(#1/1/100#)
```

This, however, will result in values containing unwanted milliseconds, thus perform the proper conversion to Date value using `CDate` which will round to the nearest second, and you have the final expression:

```
RandomDate = CDate((CLng(#12/31/9999#) - CLng(#1/1/100#)) * Rnd * Rnd + CLng(#1/1/100#))
```

Use the value as is if your field is of datatype Date or - if text - apply a format to this with `Format(RandomDate, "yyyymmddhhnnss")` and a sample output will be:

```
01770317032120
01390126010945
50140322081227
35290813165627
09330527072433
20560513105943
61810505124235
09381019130230
17010527033132
08310306233911
```

If you want numeric values, use `CDec` to convert (`CLng` will fail because of  overflow):

```
RandomNumber = CDec(Format(RandomDate, "yyyymmddhhnnss"))
```

All said, I'm with @Bohemian - if you just want a unique timestamp and have less than one transaction per second, just use data type Date for your field and use `Now`:

```
TimeStamp = Now()
```

and apply a format to this of `yyyymmddhhnnss`.

*However*, Multiplying random numbers together alters the 
 probablility distribution:

[Uniform Product Distribution](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/UniformProductDistribution.html)

Thus, a better method is to create a random date, then a random time, and possibly a random count of milliseconds - I wrote above, that CDate rounds a value to the nearest second; *it doesn't*, only whenever Access displays a date/time with milliseconds the displayed valued is rounded to the second.

So I modified the function to take care of this:

```
Public Function DateRandom( _
    Optional ByVal UpperDate As Date = #12/31/9999#, _
    Optional ByVal LowerDate As Date = #1/1/100#, _
    Optional ByVal DatePart As Boolean = True, _
    Optional ByVal TimePart As Boolean = True, _
    Optional ByVal MilliSecondPart As Boolean = False) _
    As Date

'   Generates a random date/time - optionally within the range of LowerDate and/or UpperDate.
'   Optionally, return value can be set to include date and/or time and/or milliseconds.
'
'   2015-08-28. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'   2015-08-29. Modified for uniform distribution as suggested by Stuart McLachlan by
'               combining a random date and a random time.
'   2015-08-30. Modified to return selectable and rounded value parts for
'               Date, Time, and Milliseconds.
'   2015-08-31. An initial  call of Randomize it included to prevent identical sequences.

    Const SecondsPerDay As Long = 60& * 60& * 24&

    Dim DateValue   As Date
    Dim TimeValue   As Date
    Dim MSecValue   As Date

    ' Shuffle the start position of the sequence of Rnd.
    Randomize

    ' If all parts are deselected, select date and time.
    If Not DatePart And Not TimePart And Not MilliSecondPart = True Then
        DatePart = True
        TimePart = True
    End If
    If DatePart = True Then
        ' Remove time parts from UpperDate and LowerDate as well from the result value.
        ' Add 1 to include LowerDate as a possible return value.
        DateValue = CDate(Int((Int(UpperDate) - Int(LowerDate) + 1) * Rnd) + Int(LowerDate))
    End If
    If TimePart = True Then
        ' Calculate a time value rounded to the second.
        TimeValue = CDate(Int(SecondsPerDay * Rnd) / SecondsPerDay)
    End If
    If MilliSecondPart = True Then
        ' Calculate a millisecond value rounded to the millisecond.
        MSecValue = CDate(Int(1000 * Rnd) / 1000 / SecondsPerDay)
    End If

    DateRandom = DateValue + TimeValue + MSecValue

End Function
```

Answer (score -1):

Format `now()` and cast to a long:

```
select CLng(format(now(), 'ddmmyyyyhhnnss')) as txnId
```

Although this is not "random", it is unique as long as there are never more than one transaction per second (confirmed in comment above).

Comment: Could You be more specific how to use that? (any example if possible).
It's my 1st shot with the access and VBA, I do program in C++ and i trough that vba will be relatively easy, but to be fair, it seems for me just anti logic :|

Comment: @eska oops - I gave you a java solution. Give me a minute to convert it to ms-access :)